# How to integrate an OTP service with Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I bought an OTP service from 2factor and got sample API. This OTP is to be generated while customer registration process.

Here's a sample API call

```
 <?php

$YourAPIKey='<YourAPI>';
$OTP='<OTPValue>';
$SentTo='<User10DigitNumber>';


### DO NOT Change anything below this line
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
$url = "https://2factor.in/API/V1/$YourAPIKey/SMS/$SentTo/$OTP"; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
echo curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [observer](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html) to achieve this goal. In your case, you should use observer `customer_register_success`. So now:

1. Create a new module, let's say Vendor_Module. I assume you know how to create a module. If not, refer to [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/122291/42656).
2. Create file `app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\frontend\events.xml` with the following content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
       <event name="customer_register_success">
           <observer name="call_sample_api" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\RegisterCustomer"/>
       </event>
   </config>
   ```
3. Create file `app\code\Vendor\Module\Observer\RegisterCustomer` with the following content:

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

   use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
   use \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl;
   use \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface;

   class RegisterCustomer implements ObserverInterface {
       //Your API details
       protected $YourAPIKey='<YourAPI>';
       protected $OTP='<OTPValue>';

       /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl
        */
       protected $curl;

       /**
        * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface
        */
       protected $address;

       /**
        * @param Curl $curl
        * @param AddressRepositoryInterface $address
        */
       public function __construct(
           Curl $curl,
           AddressRepositoryInterface $address
       ) {
           $this->curl = $curl;
           $this->address = $address;
       }

       public function execute(Observer $observer) {
           //I assume you use get method
           $YourAPIKey = $this->YourAPIKey;
           $OTP= $this->OTP;
           //I assume SentTo Should be get from customer registration details, refer to Note 2
           $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
           $billingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
           $billingAddress = $this->addressRepo->getById($billingAddressId);
           $SentTo= $billingAddress->getTelephone();
           //Compose URL
           $url = "https://2factor.in/API/V1/$YourAPIKey/SMS/$SentTo/$OTP";
           //See Note 1, I completely rewrite the CURL part
           $this->curl->get($url);
           $response = $this->curl->getBody();
           //Do rest of your works if applicable

       }
   }
   ```

Note 1: You can use CURL in Magento style like [this](https://webkul.com/blog/use-curl-magento-2/).

Note 2: As customer phone number is stored in address, if you want to get customer phone number, see [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189186/magento-2-customer-listing-action-get-customers-telephone).